# Performance Bottleneck with python mapping data structure

Tags: python, list, dictionary, mapping

I am facing a little performance problem with one of my data structures used for a bigger project in python.

Basically, I am importing a tabular delimited file. Using the normal python open(...) file iterator I am splitting the lines with line.split("\t"). Now I want the actual value of a column be inserted in some sort of dictionary returning an ID for the value. And there it is getting slow:

In general - the dictionary class looks like this:

```
class Dictionary(list):
  def getBitLength(self):
      if(len(self) == 0):
          return 0
      else:
          return math.log(len(self), 2)

  def insertValue(self, value):
      self.append(value)
      return len(self) - 1

  def getValueForValueId(self, valueId):
      return self[valueId]

  def getValueIdForValue(self, value):
      if(value in self):
         return self.index(value)
      else:
         return self.insertValue(value)
```

The basic idea was, that the valueId is the index of the value in the dictionary list.

Profiling the program tells me that more than 50% are spend on getValueIdForValue(...).

```
1566562 function calls in 23.218 seconds

Ordered by: cumulative time
List reduced from 93 to 10 due to restriction <10>

240000   13.341    0.000   16.953    0.000 Dictionary.py:22(getValueIdForValue)
206997    3.196    0.000    3.196    0.000 :0(index)
```

The problem is, that this is just a small test. In real application environment this function would be called several million times which would increase the runtime for this to a large extend.

Of course I could inherit from python dict, but than the performance problem is quite similar since I need to get key of a given value (in case that the value already has been inserted to the dictionary).

Since I am not the Python Pro until now, can you guys give me any tips how to make this a bit more efficient?

Best & thanks for the help,

n3otec

===

Thanks guys!

Performance of bidict is much better:

```
  240000    2.458    0.000    8.546    0.000 Dictionary.py:34(getValueIdForValue)
  230990    1.678    0.000    5.134    0.000 Dictionary.py:27(insertValue)
```

Best,
n3otec

Comment: What are you using this for?  Is your end goal every unique value you saw, paired with a unique id, and fast lookup for either direction?

Comment: Right - exactly this is my goal!

Comment: Then Hernan's answer is perfect - or you can implement yourself with two dicts.

Comment: Jip - cool. I was thinking about using two dictionaries, but I was not sure if memory consumption gets a pain than - since the data that I am importing is a rather large data set.

Comment: Good point, bidict doesn't seem to have that problem.

Comment: Note you use `try:` / `except ValueError:` instead of the `if` in that method to reduce it to one lookup from two.

Comment: Yeah did that already - thanks! But I think you mean the KeyError exception.

Answer (score 1):

If keys and values are unique, you can use a bidirectional dictionary. There is one python package [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bidict/0.1.1)